# Nested loop centering characters

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to make a tree, like the following:

```
  *
 ***
*****
 ===
```

I am able to get the tree centered, but I can't seem to get the stump to be centered with the rest of the tree. I am stuck on how to do this, any help would be appreciated!
(The stump of the tree will always have three equal signs)

```
        int height = 4;
        int counter = 1;
        int spaces = 20;
        for (int row = 1; row <= height; row++){

           for (int j = 1; j <= spaces; j++){
              System.out.print(" ");
           }

           for (int j = 1; j <= counter; j++){
              System.out.print("*");     
           }

           System.out.println("");
           counter += 2;
           spaces--;


         } // end of outer loop
         for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
            System.out.print("=");
         }
```

Comment: Do you know length of last line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int height = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int counter = 1;
        int spaces = height-1;
        for (int row = 1; row <= height; row++){

           for (int j = 1; j <= spaces; j++){
              System.out.print(" ");
           }

           for (int j = 1; j <= counter; j++){
              System.out.print("*");
           }

           System.out.println("");
           counter += 2;
           spaces--;
         } // end of outer loop
         counter-=2; // length of last line
         for(int i=1; i<=counter/2-1; i++){
            System.out.print(" ");
          }
          System.out.print("===");
    }
}
```

Observe that we leave space equal to (length of last line)/2 in the first row and it keep decreases by 1. We can find length of last line by Arithmetic Progression.

Observe that middle = of ===  will always be on (length of last line)/2+1 character. And Thus we have to put space till two characters before that that is (length)/2-1.

Comment: Does it work. If not tell me what is wrong i will try to solve.

Comment: I have generalized amount of space, now it should allign perfectly. I have tried it for many heights on local machine and it works

Comment: It does work actually! I forgot to update the spaces variable in my code. Sorry about that! Could you explain what you did exactly though? I am a bit perplexed about what you did to achieve the result.

Comment: @Theunknown I have updated answer with explaination hope it helps. I you have any doubt in explaination i can help further

Comment: The math to me is very confusing for some reason even though it appears simple. Is there a way to do it like I did before hand using the predefined amount of spaces?

Comment: @TejasPatel spaces is just height-1. Edited answer.

Comment: @danielkullmann yes true, didn't see that first, thanks for update

Comment: @Theunknown If you want generalized you can't keep static height and space

Comment: @TejasPatel I was getting confused over the spaces variable but it makes sense now. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it!